# Get all column value in Sqllite in android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have saved product name in one column in `Sqllite`  database .Lot of product name are already saved there now, I need to get all product name sent it to web service.For example egg, briyani, idly.
I have used it this code in `Sqllite` but String is not append.I have mention below this code:

```
public String fetchMyRowid(String column_name)
    {
        String query = "select  "+column_name+" From " + TABLErestaurant;

        mCursor =db.rawQuery(query, null);
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
        if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {

            buf.append(mCursor.getString(0)+",");

        }

       return buf.toString();
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
 buf.append(mCursor.getString(0)+",");
}
```

The problem is you're not iterating through your results. Do this instead:

```
while(mCursor.moveToNext()) {

 buf.append(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(column_name))+",");

}
```

Comment: Also check `mCursor != null` before calling `mCursor.moveToNext()`

Answer (score 0):

your code is fine but you forgate: `db.getWritableDatabase();` or `getreadableDatabase()`

i have modify your code here `DBController` is my class `public class DBController extends SQLiteOpenHelper`

so your code ll be..

```
public String fetchMyRowid(String column_name, DBController db) {
        String query = "SELECT  " + column_name + " FROM " + TABLErestaurant;
        SQLiteDatabase dd = db.getWritableDatabase();
        cursor = dd.rawQuery(query, null);
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
        if(cursor.getCount() > 0 || cursor != null){

             do {

              Log.e("name--->", "" + cursor.getString(0));
              buf.append(cursor.getString(0) + ",");

              } while (cursor.moveToNext());

              Log.e("name---> buffeer-->", "" + buf);

          }

        return buf.toString();
    }
```

Comment: StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer(); after return statement called.It wont go to in If condition

Comment: same problem we can't go to if condition.But value is added in cursor

Comment: only return statement it's called

Comment: ya i checked  Dhaval Sodha Parmar value is have in cursor

Comment: i have remove it if condition but same problem occurred.

Answer (score -1):

Just make a small change here,

instead of this line ,

```
String query = "select  "+column_name+" From " + TABLErestaurant;
```

try this line

```
String query = "select  * From " + TABLErestaurant;
```